# How to represent the coordinates of a point

Tags: notation

I would like to know what is the more appropriate way to represent a coordinate of a point in the Cartesian coordinate system.

For example, if I have a point $A$, how should I represent its $x$ coordinate? $A_x$, $x_A$ or in another way?

Comment: If you are using ordinal numbers eg: $0, 1, 2 \dots$, you can refer to the point as $(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), \dots$. If you are referring to them as $A(x,y), B(x, y)$, the $A_x, B_x$ etc., is fine. You may also refer to them as $x_A, x_B$. It is a matter of preference. As long as you clarify your notation and are consistent, it should not matter.